# "command not found" when running shell script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Here is the simple `script.sh` file I have:

```
#!/bin/bash
pwd
date
ls -lg
```

I have used `chmod +x` to make the file executable, but when running it with `./script.sh` I get `command not found: pwd` `command not found: date` and only the `ls -lg` command works. I'm a bit perplexed as to why the first two commands aren't working because when I type them into the command terminal they work the way they should.

Comment: Are there carriage returns in your script?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Can you edit the post and copy-paste complete and exact error messages? (Just everything from your terminal including `yourprompt$ ./script.sh` until the script exits.) This is very helpful in file and character encoding issues, because even a missing or additional space, period or colon can hint at what's wrong and where.

Comment: Try `cat -A script.sh`. This will show you any hidden characters. If `cat -A` doesn't work, try `cat -v`.

Comment: Maybe your (non-interactive) bash path is all messed up. Try adding some `echo`'s in there, like `echo $PATH`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe there is a (invisible) character there that should not be there. Try typing it again from scratch in the environment that it will run (ex: Linux) or use this command `od -c /folder/script.sh` to reveal those pesky characters.

Comment: Thanks, there did in fact appear to be an invisible character somewhere. I retyped the file from scratch and suddenly it worked just fine.

Answer (score 4):

Also do not use a variable called PATH (cause it is already used :)

Comment: how valuable clue you gave us. I was making mistake and wasn't work my code just because I used a variable with name PATH