# command not found when running script

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to run program *midnight commander* by `script.sh` and I can run it by using `sh`, but when I try to run it without `sh`, I get:

> script.sh: command not found

This is `script.sh`:

```
#!bin/bash
mc
```

I found some answers regarding this topic(["command not found" when running shell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43771597/command-not-found-when-running-shell-script)). In this answer they suggested to run command `od -c script.sh` to reveal invisible characters.
This was the result of that command.

```
0000000 # ! / b i n / b a s h \n m c \n
0000017
```

I think that this command did not reveal hidden characters.

Can someone tell me what is the problem here?

Comment: Please copy&paste the script or commands and output to your question, don't retype. `#!bin/bash` in the script does not match the `od` output `# ! / b i n / b a s h \n`. There is a missing or additional `/`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first give execute permission to `script.sh`

```
chmod +x script.sh
```

then `./script.sh`

Comment: This one is working.

But can you tell me why is `script.sh` not working(without `./`)?

Comment: Because commands are search in PATH and the directory `script.sh` is in is not in PATH.

Comment: I've been thru the same issue on an Ubuntu with [oh-my-bash](https://github.com/ohmybash/oh-my-bash) installed. With `.` added to PATH on a terminal session, not `.bashrc` or `.profile`, like said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47255247/5938182), the script runs as expected when called by name, without `./` before. I think there's a configuration for this, but I couldn't figure it out a solution. On another PC with a clean Ubuntu 20.04, it works as expected. Then it would be interesting to know what is causing that issue.